# String[].Count() giving strange result

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am debugging some code, and came across this strange scenario.  A method takes a `String[]` variable, and it first checks if the variable is *null*...

```
protected override CommandResult OnExecute(DateTime closeOfBusinessDate, 
                                                                string[] verbs)
        {
            if (verbs == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("verbs");
            }
```

We get passed this line, and the next check it to make sure the variable has no more than one value...

```
 if (verbs.Count() > 1)
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("Only single verb supported.", "verbs");
     }
```

It's pretty basic stuff, but during debugging, I am seeing this result...
[image]

As you can see, the `Count()` is **1**, yet the check still evaluates to true for `if (verbs.Count() > 1)`, can anyone explain this? maybe I'm missing something obvious.

**EDIT**: Added Output

You can see in the output window, the value is **1**.

[image]

Comment: Try to print verbs.Count() before the if statement

Comment: could you please post the verbs array? thanks !

Comment: I can't comment on the strange behaviour, but I have to ask if the method requires exactly one verb, why does it take an array?

Comment: The code isn't actually mine, I'm just debugging it to make changes - but the comments suggest that it will take an array in the future.

Comment: Pretty strange if code is exactly what you show, especially because AFAIK an array won't change its size without changing reference too  (in case of concurrent access). BTW why `.Count()` instead of `.Length`?

Comment: Like Ahmad suggested, I've learned not to trust IDE's too much. Try `Console.WriteLine(verbs.Count().ToString());` The line before this if-statement just incase

Comment: This is a problem due to the string[] which is getting passed. 
verbs.Count() will always return the size of the array. 
so if you have an string[] = new string[3];
verb.Count will return 3

Comment: Are you sure the build is from this code and not an old code that has been modified. Sometimes, a clean-build solves the problem.

Comment: Clean, Rebuild, worst case restart the VS and problem should go away(I hope).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, sure, I can change this to `Length` and the issue might go away, but I was just curious to why `Count()` was giving this strange result.

Comment: @adityaswami89 That doesn't explain why `verbs.Count() > 1` is evaluating to `true` when the count is `1`.

Comment: Is the `.Count()` call actually bound to the [`Enumerable.Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038.aspx) extension method?

Comment: @cynic, yes, it's the standard one.

Comment: @christiandev yes, behavior is still weird, I was just curious if there was a special reason for that.

Comment: Can you post **exact code and signature** of that method and (possibly) **caller code** too?

Comment: Assuming you use c# 4+, could you please inspect it using OzCode plugin. It uses a new feature of VS2013 to show return values of function calls. details are in http://o.oz-code.com/new-beta-release-big-news-visual-studio-2013-users-tons-of-improvements

Comment: I will update the question with the comments later.  Why -1?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
    static void Example()
    {
        var verbs = new string[] { null, null };
        checkBerbs(verbs);
    }

    static void checkVerbs(string[] verbs)
    {
        if (verbs.Count() > 1)
        {
            mutateArray(ref verbs); //this would run another thread --> race condition
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    private static void mutateArray(ref string[] verbs)
    {
        verbs = new string[] { null };
    }
```

This is a possible scenario. Not knowing the full extent of your code I'm not sure if this is even possible. Evidently `mutateArray` would be running on another thread and you would have a race condition. Maybe locking `verbs` can give you a clue about this being some concurrency issue.

Comment: It may happen if you _mutate_ array inside Example() but array passed as method parameter is by value (then if same variable is passed with ref to another method...array "received" by first method won't be changed.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. If you call mutateArray() inside checkVerbs() then what you describe may happen (but I guess OP wouldn't be surprised in that case...). If you call mutateArray() inside Example() then array received by checkVerbs() won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the code is actually calling the `Enumerable.Count` extension method and no trickery is in place, the problem is you are assuming the next statement to be executed is the `throw` statement.

The two situations most likely to result in the debugger *appearing* to be in one location even though it is not are:

1. Compiling with optimizations enabled (very common; the default in the **Release** configuration).
2. Using IL rewriting tools that do not properly update debugging information (not particularly common).

Recompiling or running the code using a **Debug** configuration will likely show you that the `throw` statement is not actually reached.

Comment: +1000^0 for you if he didn't step to see if instruction will be executed or not...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Neither the original question nor any comment from @christiandev indicate that he stepped over the `throw` statement to verify that it is actually getting thrown, nor do they suggest that the test was run with the Optimize Code setting disabled (e.g. **Debug** configuration).

Answer (score -1):

Count doesn't work like that. Use `verbs.Length` instead

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure I can tell you why you are seeing that result, but I can suggest a fix: use verbs.Length instead of verbs.Count(). In this case Count() is a LINQ method while Length is the array property that will tell you the number of items in the array.

Comment: Clearly Count() is giving the wrong answer. It is a more expensive piece of code to run than Length, which gives the right answer. So as a practical matter, Count() is wrong...